# Can ccmake output the equivalent cmake command?

Tags: cmake

Lets say I set up a build with ccmake. I only changed two options, and the equivalent cmake command is (as an example):

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${HOME}/apps ..
```

I would like to save this line for future use and as documentation on the procedure.

Can ccmake generate/print this command for me?